# Accessing public images from CSS file in production cordova build

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I'm having trouble getting my image paths to work within my CSS files when building my cordova app for production. I have this image path, that compiles correctly through webpack, however because it has a slash at the beginning of the path, my cordova app cannot find the image correctly, as it can't have a trailing slash at the start of the path.

`background-image: url('/img/backgrounds/spots/lime.jpg');`

I have set publicPath within my vue.config.js: `publicPath: ''`

Once running on the phone it tries to reference this image:

> background-image: url(/img/backgrounds/spots/navy.jpg)

However it requires it to be this filepath:

> background-image: url(img/backgrounds/spots/navy.jpg)

How can I make sure that within my cordova production build I don't have the slash at the start of the path. I also cannot remove the slash out of the path within the CSS file, because then webpack will fail to compile all-together.

Hope that makes sense, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `./` (dot-slash)